# How to insert in B+ Tree?

Tags: database, indexing, tree, computer-science, b-tree

I have the following set `1,2,3,4,6,8,12,15`

I'm trying to insert these numbers in ascending order to an 
empty tree that has `m=3` number of pointers.

I tried many tools but I'm getting different results not sure which one is correct.

This is from [cs.usfca.edu](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BPlusTree.html)
[image]

And this one is from [goneill.co.nz](https://goneill.co.nz/btree-demo.php)

[image]

Why I'm getting different results ?

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid B+ trees (of order 3) for the set `1,2,3,4,6,8,12,15`. The solution from [cs.usfca.edu](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BPlusTree.html) is what one would expect if the set is entered as ordered (i.e., from 1 onwards) with the branching going left if "less than" and right if "greater than or equal". It is unclear to me with what order of insertion [goneill.co.nz](https://goneill.co.nz/btree-demo.php) gets to its result (and I don't have Java installed, so I can't run the script). However he/she gives a [detailed explanation](https://goneill.co.nz/btree-notes.php) as to the procedure followed there.

For an explanation of how to insert/delete in a B+ tree, there is a descent set of slides [here](https://www.slideshare.net/bitistu/b-tree).